# Dropdownlist shows a random selection instead of user selected on submit

Tags: html, asp.net

HTML code for dropdown list is

```
 <div style="float: left; width: 100%; margin-top: 5px;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 42%;">
            <span class="Red_Bold_70">* </span>
            <asp:Label ID="lblStateTitle" runat="Server" Text="State/Province: " CssClass="NoColor_Bold_70"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 54%; padding-left: 4px;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" CssClass="NoColor__70">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvStateDDL" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* State is required" ControlToValidate="ddlState" CssClass="Red__70" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server" CssClass="NoColor__70" Width="50%" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvStateTextBox" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* State is required" ControlToValidate="txtState" CssClass="Red__70" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

        PopulateCountryDDL()
        PopulateStateDDL()
   end if 
end sub
```

The populateStateDDL retrives the states from the data source.

```
 Protected Sub ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlState.SelectedIndexChanged


        selectedState = ddlState.SelectedValue.ToString()

End Sub
```

When I checked the value of the selected item of ddlstate I see a random value other than the selected on submit.however it works good for few selections and constantly isn't for few.Can you suggest what might be the issue here?

Comment: Is it really a random value ? Or following some pattern . as in if you selected first value in dropdown selectedState turns out to be second value instead ?

Comment: It shows one of value in the list. It isn't following any fixed pattern. As mentioned it works good for few selections.

Comment: What do you mean by "few selections" ? Please elaborate

Comment: For example if my dropdownlist contains 1.A 2.B 3.C 4.D 5.E When I select 2 i.e, B it is working fine. The ddlState.Selectedvalue is B. but when I select 4.D the value shown at the ddlState.SelectedValue is A. This is reproducible any no of times I do.

Comment: @suji8886 I'm curious. Are they cascading dropdownlists because I'm seeing Country and State? If so, please upload **PopulateCountryDDL**, **PopulateStateDDL** and **ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged**?

Comment: We need to see the populate subs.  For instance, I've seen people cache the drop down lists (the actual controls and not just the values to re-load).  When the control is cached the state of what is selected can reach over sessions per se.  One user selects a value and then the next user has that value selected.  I had to fix a site where this happened and seemingly random items were being selected.